# Travis-ci: npm install on windows

Tags: node.js, selenium, npm, travis-ci, saucelabs

Due to the large unexpected problems with Windows, I have the following requirement in my project:

> As a developer I want to be notified every time `npm install` fails on Windows.

So what is the recommended approach to write this type of "integration" test, assuming I'm using Travis-CI? Can I run npm install on Windows inside Sauce Labs?

I thought on writing a script that does that: (is Selenium the best tool for that?)

- Clone the latest stable build (that passed CI)
- Run `npm install` on windows
- Start the Node.JS express server locally
- Open the local application on IE 9+, Chrome, Firefox.
- Try to download some assets from the website and make sure they work

This script should fail and exit immediately if any of these step fails.

Comment: did you manage to run node.js on windows on travis ? I'm searching for the same things